# How to run MAGMI from a shell script

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, magento

I try to run MAGMI from a shellscript, but I get allways the same message:

/bin/sh: /is/htdocs/XXXXXXXXX/magento/magmi/cli/XXXXXXX.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

My script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

FILES=/is/htdocs/XXXXXXXXX/magento/var/import/XXXXXXXXX.csv
for f in $FILES
do
     echo "Running Magmi update with file: $f"
     php magmi.cli.php -profile=XXXX -mode=update -CSV:filename="${f}"
     wait
done
```

The script is in the same directory as magmi.cli.php

Thanks for hints and solutions !

Answer (score 1):

Please use dos2unix linux command to remove above error like:

```
 dos2unix scriptfilename.sh scriptfilename.sh
```

it generally occurs when we written something in WINDOW eniv. & then transfer to Linux platform

Comment: I solved this by using the convert option of Notepad++. Thanks for directing to the right direction !